# Calculate the Mean and STD sub-setting a dynamic set of columns

Tags: r

Calculate the Mean and STD sub-setting a dynamic set of columns.

to show it as an example:

```
sales <- data.frame(ItemID=c("1A","1B","1C"),
           Jul=c(0,1,5),
           Aug=c(1,2,6),
           Sep=c(0,3,7),
           Oct=c(1,4,8),
           Nov=c(1,4,8),
           Dec=c(1,4,8),
           Jan=c(1,4,8),
           Nmon=c(7,4,6))
```

The above test data gives the below below table. What I would need is to apply functions on each row based on the value in the "Nmon" column.

```
  ItemID Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec Jan Nmon
1     1A   0   1   0   1   1   1   1    7
2     1B   1   2   3   4   4   4   4    4
3     1C   5   6   7   8   8   8   8    6
```

e.g. the first record has the Nmon value as 7. Then I need to calculate the mean and standard deviation of all the values from Jul to Jan (mean = 0.71, std = 0.49).

In case of second record where the Nmon value is 4 the mean and standard deviation should only be calculated for the the months ranging from Oct-Jan (mean = 4, std = 0)

Here the number of months will increase or decrease but the first(Item number) and last (Nmon) columns will remain the same.
I have a large data set of items and need an efficient way to do this calculations.

Comment: The index for the first record is 7 which tells us that we need to take the data of 7 months starting in this example from Jan (which lest assume that is the latest month) to Jul.

Comment: Where as when it is 4 it should consider only the from Jan (current month) to October.

Comment: ok thanks, I posted a solution.  Please let me know if that is what you wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this helps

```
 t(apply(sales[-1], 1, function(x) {i1 <- length(x)
        x2 <- x[(i1 -x[i1]):(i1-1)]
       c(mean = mean(x2), sd = sd(x2))}))
 #        mean      sd
 #[1,] 0.7142857 0.48795
 #[2,] 4.0000000 0.00000
 #[3,] 7.5000000 0.83666
```

Comment: Thank you very much... yes it worked.....I have been going round the issue for some time.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution with base R:

```
sales <- data.frame(ItemID=c("1A","1B","1C"),
                    Jul=c(0,1,5),
                    Aug=c(1,2,6),
                    Sep=c(0,3,7),
                    Oct=c(1,4,8),
                    Nov=c(1,4,8),
                    Dec=c(1,4,8),
                    Jan=c(1,4,8),
                    Nmon=c(7,4,6))
my.m.sd <- function(i) {
  n <- sales$Nmon[i]
  x <- unlist(sales[i, seq(to=8, length.out = n)])
  c(m=mean(x), s=sd(x))
}
sapply(1:3, my.m.sd)
# > sapply(1:3, my.m.sd)
#        [,1] [,2]    [,3]
# m 0.7142857    4 7.50000
# s 0.4879500    0 0.83666
```